# Regional date format when updating recordset in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm based in the UK and am developing an Access 2016 DB for a client in the US.

I need to update some dates in a table programmatically and I've done so by  editing a RecordSet.

My question is this: If I provide the dates in UK format (dd/mm/yyyy) will the database store it as US format (mm/dd/yyyy) on my clients computers?

I've no way to test this without changing my regional settings in Windows which I'm not keen to do.

Thanks.

Comment: If in doubt, go for yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Provide dates as dates, not strings.

Comment: @ Adrian - Thanks, good idea

Comment: @ Comintern - They are dates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't provide a format but a *value*. Formats are for display only.

```
Dim Date1 As Date

' Set Date1 to some value.
Date1 = DateSerial(2016, 10, 15)

rs!YourDateField.Value = Date1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sure, I get that, but what if the (dd/mm/yyy) date is something like 01/02/2016? With my regional settings that's what DateSerial(2016, 2, 1) will return. If in the US would it return 02/01/2016? The MSDN page for DateSerial is not specific about this.

Comment: @Absinthe the *format* is a **representation** of the `Date` value; it is NOT the value itself. As long as you have `Date` values `As Date`, you don't have to worry about its representation.

Comment: @Absinthe - `DateSerial` has nothing to do with regional settings. It takes specific year, month, day arguments.

Comment: The MSDN page for DateSerial is very specific about this; the three parameters determine the resulting date value.